TextInput State
this is my python file content i made a mysql data base and connected it to the program and i have a problem with the home screen because i am trying to make a search bar
from kivy.app import App
import mysql.connector
from arabic_reshaper import reshape
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
sm=ScreenManager()
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="A.C.A_2024",
    database="users_data"
)
my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
data=my_cursor.fetchall()
def arab(text):
    return get_display(reshape(text))


class LoginPageLayout(Screen):
    error_text=StringProperty("")
    def SignIn(self,username,password):
        print("hello")
        for i in data:
            if i[0] == username and i[1] == password:
                print("hi")
                print(username)
                print(password)
                sm.current="HomePage"
        print("try again")

class SignUpLayout(Screen):
    error_text = StringProperty("")
    def SignUp(self,username,password):
        if len(username)<8:
            self.error_text="user name must be 8 charcters atleast"
        elif len(password)<8:
            self.error_text="password must be 8 characters atleast"
        else:
            print("hello")
            my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data (username , password) VALUES (%s , %s)", (username, password))
            mydb.commit()
            print("done excecuting")
            sm.current = "HomePage"
class HomePage(Screen):
    pass






class ACAapp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(LoginPageLayout(name="LoginPageLayout"))
        sm.add_widget(SignUpLayout(name="SignUpLayout"))
        sm.add_widget(HomePage(name="HomePage"))
        return sm


ACAapp().run()

and this is my kivy file
<LoginPageLayout>:

    BoxLayout:
        padding: [50,10,50,30]
        spacing: 20
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "login page"
            font_name: "andlso.ttf"
        TextInput:
            id: user
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False
            password: True
        Button:
            font_name: "andlso.ttf"
            text: "login"
            on_press: root.SignIn(user.text , password.text)
        Button:
            font_name: "andlso.ttf"
            text: "don`t have an account? sign up"
            on_press: root.manager.current="SignUpLayout"

<SignUpLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        font_size: 40
        padding: [50,10,50,30]
        spacing: 20
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "sign up page"
            font_name: "andlso.ttf"
        TextInput:
            id: user2
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: pass2
            multiline: False
            password: True
        Label:
            text: root.error_text
            font_name: "andlso.ttf"
        Button:
            text: "sign up"
            on_press: root.SignUp(user2.text,pass2.text)
<HomePage>:
    canvas.before:
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: 50 , self.height-75
            size: self.width-50 , 50
            radius: [(40,40),(40,40),(40,40),(40,40)]
    TextInput:
        size_hint: (None , None)
        width: root.width-100
        height: 50
        pos: 75 , root.height-75


signup and signin screens are already done and i am working on the home page
i tried to make a search bar in the home screen but the color of the text input when active is diffrent from the color of the rectangle

To specify the color of the text for TextInput in kivy you can edit or add properties and customize with a canvas:

TextInput:
    height: dp(40)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "top": .975}
    font_size: "14sp"
    hint_text_color: [0,0,0, .7]
    foreground_color: [0,.1,1,1]
    background_color: [1,1,1,0]
    background_image: "a11.png" #this was a 100% transparent png image I use
    background_normal: "a11.png"
    background_active: "a11.png"
    multiline: False
    size_hint: .5 ,None
    hint_text: 'Search here'
    on_text: 'results or do somethin'
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: [.42,.05,.6,.6]
        Line:
            width: dp(2)
            rounded_rectangle:
                (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
                dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),\
                dp(50))

